# How can I use gradle Integration for eclipse and how can I create build.gradle in eclipse

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-eclipse

I downloaded the gradle plugin from eclipse market place. but can't able to create built.gradle in my project. 
For downloading the plugin I use this link http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/. From this link I specifically select Core/Eclipse integration for gradle and downloaded the plugin. After that I don't know how to use built.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the project then in the context menu: New -> File, enter the name of the file as "build.gradle" and click OK.

Comment: Can u help me on building gradle? I don't have any idea about gradle. I want to use this for "Android Project Dependencies" and "Android multidex support library using eclipse"

Comment: For that what steps I have to follow? Shall I install gradle on my desktop for this? Any thing will be good for me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Don't think you need to install Gradle separately on your Desktop since Gradle Eclipse plugin comes with Gradle runtime I believe. Yet you can still install Gradle runtime and point to it via Eclipse Preferences. There must be some tutorial how to use Gradle for Android projects... I don't deal with Android lately, so can't help there.